# The given path's format is not supported. Error during file download from Asp.net Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Here i Wrote simple c# code for Download Excel sheet from WebApi
but during the download im Getting Error As `The given path's format is not supported.`
please Help Me

```
 public HttpResponseMessage GetTestFile()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage result = null;
         //   var localFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/C:/Temp/3c575edb-bf53-470c-a8b6-aa4234e796c0");
           var localFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/C:/Temp/3c575edb-bf53-470c-a8b6-aa4234e796c0");


            if (!File.Exists(localFilePath))
            {
                result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Gone);
            }
            else
            {
                // Serve the file to the client
                result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                result.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
                result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
                result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "SampleImg";
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapPath works only for the files in your virtual directory, not the files outside your project. **So always include the files that you need into your project and then use mappath.** 
`var localFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Temp/3c575edb-bf53-470c-a8b6-aa4234e796c0");`

```
localFilePath //it will contain your_project_path/Temp/3c575edb-bf53-470c-a8b6-aa4234e796c0
e.g: F:\projectname\Temp\3c575edb-bf53-470c-a8b6-aa4234e796c0
```

Comment: An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: // This will locate the Example.txt file in the root directory.
// ... This can be used in a file in any directory in the application.
`string localFilePath  = HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~/Example.txt");`. Got idea? So in your case is `3c575edb-bf53-470c-a8b6-aa4234e796c0` a folder?

Comment: its present in C:/Temp  Folder with the Name of  3c575edb-bf53-470c-a8b6-aa4234e796c0

Comment: your Example Help me a lot But Here any Idea about that HeaxaDecimal File path?

Comment: :=) Welcome, glad to be of your service.